# Codenameone: Picker on iPad no longer has any buttons

Tags: codenameone

Starting with the build of my App today the native Picker-Dialog on my iPad (iOS 13.3.1 - real Device - no simulator) don't have buttons any more (see Screenshot). The buttons are there on my iPhone 11 (iOS 13.3.1) with the same build. The buttons have been there with a build earlier this week.

Are there any changes in CN1 which could cause this behaviour?

Without these Buttons a new selection cannot be confirmed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a native picker and not the lightweight picker which is more consistently reliable.

This is probably a bug but to help us quantify it please check if it's a bug triggered by the migration to xcode 11.3: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/xcode-11-migration-now-default.html

Assuming it is you can use xcode 10.1 for now. To avoid such issues I would suggest using the lightweight mode of the picker which is more consistently reliable across platforms.

Comment: I tested with xcode 10.1 - and the Picker Dialog has all buttons. So it seems to be because of the migration to xcode 11.3. I will use the lightweight mode for now.

Comment: OK, I suggest filing an issue too so this won't get lost if you ever want to return to the heavyweight picker.

Comment: Ok - I filed an issue: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3055